# Dynamically check text input

Tags: jquery, text, input

I'd like to create an input form that has an asterisk after the box for each required field. If the user enters a string the asterisk should change to a exclamation mark. Right now the javascript code just adds an exclamation mark every time the user types a letter.

HTML:

```
<form name="form1">
<ul>
<li><input type='text' name ='text1' required placeholder="required"/></li>
<li><input type='text' name ='text1' required placeholder="required"/></li>
<li><input type='text' name ='text1' placeholder="not required"/></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

JAVA/JQUERY:

```
 $(function() {
        $('input:required').after( "<span>*</span>" );  

    });

 $('input:required').keyup(function(){
    var dInput = this.value;
    if(dInput.length > 0)
    //if($('input:required').is(':valid'))
    {
        $(this).after("<span>!</span>")
    }
 });
```

Thx for you help!

Comment: You want that if a user enter a string then its change to exclamation sign , and right now its changing when you type letter , so whats the difference between string and letter ?

Comment: a string can also contain numbers, right?
However, I can't get the main mechanism right so that the code checks if the user has entered something and gives a visual feedback (e.g. an exclamation mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that your **`.after` will add a `span` element each time you call it**, you can get back the previsouly created span element using `.parent().children("span")`and then change its content :

```
 $(this).parent().children("span").text("!")
```

instead of :

```
$(this).after("<span>!</span>")
```

This is the simplest way to correct your code, but is probably not the best way to do what you want.

The `$('input').keyup()` is a good approach for a full-control real time validation, but you could also take a look at the [`validation` plugin of jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

**EDIT**

Example using a `span` id instead of navigating through the DOM tree, this would allow you to move the `span` tag anywhere in the HTML tree without breaking the JavaScript code :

```
$(function() {
    $('input:required').each(function(index) {
        var id = this.form.name+this.name+"mark";
        $(this).after( "<span id='"+id+"'>*</span>" ); 
    });
});

$('input:required').keyup(function(){
    if(this.value.length > 0) {
        var id = this.form.name+this.name+"mark";
        $("#"+id).text("!");
    }
});
```

Note that for this to work, you inputs should have unique names inside your form.

Also note that the `span` tags and their corresponding `id` could be statically written in the HTML or generated by the server instead of being generated by the client in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers, really appreciate it.
That would be my next question: Is my approach the right one or is there a better way to solve what I want to do?

Comment: The `$('input').keyup()` is a good approach, it's just the `.parent().children()` which is not very neat. You could add some id to   get the `span` tag corresponding to your `input` tag.

Comment: true but the problem is that then I'd have to assign an ID to every single text input. If there's 10 input's I needed 10 IDs. I just want to keep my code as flexible as possible. What do you think?

Comment: You could automatically add an id to the span tag when creating it, the id could be some combination of the form name and the input name (which should be unique unlike in your code).

Comment: good thought! the only problem is that you'd have to store all ids, since your code only works with one input field. I do like the idea of creating a unique id by using the input parameters.

Comment: @FLuttenb I only posted an example for the first input, but your can loop over all the input. You don't have to store the id, just see my last edit. Also don't forget to put unique input names in your form.

Comment: thx for the help! it works now and I even adapted it to select dropdowns :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [.foucsout()](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/). As soon as focus is lost from a text field, say, by pressing tab key to jump to next field or button. Test in `.focusout()` callback for length and append '!'

Also, refer to @zakinster solution. His solution will help you out in replacing '*' to '!'. As, I understood this, I suggested .focusout(), so that it replaces asterisk to exclamation when user has completed typing his input and his input can then be judged.