# UI: Separating Multiple Inputs With Comma

Tags: flask, input, multi-select, flask-wtforms

I am wondering how to achieve this with Flask and WTForms for UI purposes. This input takes up to 10 responses separated by comma. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ5Zm.png)

I hope for each response to be cemented in the input after the user types in a comma for UI purposes (I can handle it on the backend). So for example, they type in "Red," and "Red" is cemented in the input with the ability to delete it. Any library suggestions or ideas on how I should attack this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need JavaScript to do this. This question might be of some help: [Dynamically check text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231100/dynamically-check-text-input). I would do a search on dynamically checking text input.